# Setting user privileges in PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, session, privileges

I want to make some of my php pages accessible to certain users. I flag these users in my users table as 'super_user' in the 'user_privilege' attribute. So fat I have got the login and sessions working. But I'm not sure about 'super_user' only pages. Basically this is the page I want to make accessible only to super users:

```
<?php
require_once('../includes/su_permission.inc.php');
require_once('../includes/session_timeout_db.inc.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Secret page</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Restricted area</h1>
<p><a href="menu_db.php">Back to restricted menu</a> </p>
<?php include('../includes/logout_db.inc.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The session_timeout_db.inc.php doc checks if the user's session has expired and it works fine. I have also added this: require_once('../includes/su_permission.inc.php'); in the code to check if the user is a super user. This my attempt at the code:

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$conn = new mysqli ($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Connection Failed");

$sql = 'SELECT user_role FROM users WHERE user_email = ?';

$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param('s', $user_email);

$stmt->bind_result($user_role);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetch();

if ($user_role='SU') {
  $_SESSION['privilege_level'] = $user_role;

// some other code needed here
  exit;
} else {
  echo 'No permission to visit this page';
}
```

I know it is a poor attempt, but I'm not sure what else to do from here. Can someone please advice the best way I can do this ?

Thanks

Comment: So what Sepcific erros are you getting (if any)? Have you done any debugging to try to determine where you code might have it's problems?  Are you really intending to call `exit` when the user has successfully authenticated?  This would stop the rest of the page from being output.

Comment: @MikeBrant I removed the exit part and ran the code and it still gives access to the user who is not flagged as a super user in the database. I just don't know if the method I'm using is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
if ($user_role='SU') {
```

You need a proper comparison operator (`==` or `===`) here.  What you are doing right now is assigning a value of `SU` to `$user_role` in all cases.

A slight programming suggestion to avoid such problems is to flip to comparison order like this:

```
if ('SU' == $user_role) {
```

That way if you accidentally type `=` instead of `==` or `===`, you will get an error output, rather than having your code quietly run while doing something you don't want it to do.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, I changed it to == now it says no permission to view this page but it actually views what I have on the page. I just want it to display the no permission error and not display anything else.

Comment: @elmify That's where the `exit` comes in handy :)

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for being patient with me but I added the exit just here:  $_SESSION['privilege_level'] = $user_role;


  exit;

Comment: (continued) still no changes, I'm not sure if I should add something like $_SESSION['privilege_level'] = $user_role; in the restricted page

Comment: You would want to add the `exit` in the side of the conditional where you don't want the page displayed, but rather just the "no permission" message. So place it after that message.

Comment: I have got one more question for you, what if I want to display it to 'admin' users as well ? I changed my code to this

Comment: if ($user_role=='SU' || $user_role=='ADM') {
  $_SESSION['privilege_level'] = $user_role; however it didn't seem to work. It doesn't give permission to the user even though it has the admin user role

Comment: @elmify Hard to say without debugging.. What value do you get for `$user_role`?

Comment: this actually doesn't work if the users role is super user, it always says no permission to view this page to every user :(

Comment: Again,  it is hard to say where your problem is without debugging.  You need to verify you are getting the value(s) you expect in `$user_role`

Comment: ok yes my problem was that I couldn't get any values for user_email. So I moved it to another file where I pass the value for user_email. It works perfectly now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar thing on the site I'm working on. I setup up three different areas, for the different user 'types'.

I then setup 3 different session check files for the groups of pages. I'm sure this could be done using only one file, and some elseifs but whatever. Anyway here is the code snippet that I use on my pages to check if a user is logged in, and if they are the right "type" of user to view the page:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['authenticated']) && $_SESSION['authenticated'] !== 'admin') {

//if (!isset($_SESSION['authenticated'])) {
  header("Location: $redirect");
  exit;
```

If they aren't right it redirects them. I hope that helps.